# Is cross-validation with no data leakage sufficient to replace train-test split?

Tags: cross-validation, train-test-split

I would like to seek expert advice on the topic above.

I was taught to follow this workflow:

1. Split dataset into training and testing
2. Use training dataset to develop model

   - Set hyperparameter in model
   - Do cross-validation (multiple train-validation splits, tests, measures)
   - Repeat with different hyperparameter set until performance of train is near to validation
3. Thereafter, check performance of final chosen model on testing dataset

My thoughts are:

1. Testing dataset is chosen once
2. It might not be representative
3. Hence performance might not be representative also, be it good or bad

My questions are:

1. Given this situation, would result from cross-validation be good gauge of model performance?
2. If this is the case, then **train-test split might not be needed**
3. Of course during cross-validation, it is important not to have data leakage

I would love to hear your thoughts. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. The question: Is there a need to do train-test split before cross-validation? I feel that cross-validation on the whole dataset should be sufficient. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion might stem from a clash of workflows. Your workflow includes a step *Repeat with different hyperparameter set until performance of train is near to validation* whereas the typical workflow that I am familiar with would include a step *Repeat with different hyperparameter set and select the one which performs best on the validation data*.

In the latter case, a train-test split is needed for a fair evaluation of the selected model's performance on new data. In the cross-validation stage with hyperparameter tuning, the performance of the best model on the hold-out data is optimistically biased. This is because the selection of the best tuning parameter involves some luck in addition to skill, a luck that would not be replicated on an independent test set. You can see that for yourself using simulation.

If you do not want a fair evaluation of the selected model's performance on new data, then you can skip the train-test split and tune and select the model using cross-validation alone. This would be an efficient use of data for the purpose.

With your workflow, first I am not sure whether it is likely to produce the optimal hyperparameter and then am I not sure what to expect from the selected model applied on new data. Again, simulations could help get some insight into that. There does not seem to be a built-in mechanism for an overly optimistic performance on the validation data, so perhaps the train-test split is unnecessary. But that is just a guess.

Another point: if your sample is representative, it is unlikely that a randomly chosen test set is not representative. If your randomly chosen test set is not representative, then it is likely that your whole sample is not representative, so not splitting into training and test will not help.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thank you very much for your enlightening answers. (1) Yes. What I meant was "repeat with different hyperparameter sets and select the set which performs best", the best being training closest to validation. (2) Noted on your explanation where train-test split can be skipped. I will simulate and put on GitHub. (3) I agree with you on representativeness of the sample. My initial thought was there will be sampling error and with bad luck, the sample can be far off the population, something type I error. Anyway, really appreciate your help on this topic. There's so much to learn :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Richard. I have checked the tick. Let's wait to hear from others to learn together. I will look up the URL you've provided. Have a great day!